# Getting IDCompositionDevice of the current HWND

Tags: c++, xaml, com, windows-runtime, composition

Is there a way to get the current instance of `IDCompositionDevice` used for rendering by (Win32) Windows.UI.Xaml (like in Xaml Islands, XamlPresenter, or XamlHost) for the current HWND/Thread without using WinRT at all?
Like without casting `Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor` or using any WinRT (Windows.UI.Composition.*) APIs?
I'm sure that there's a way to do so, like searching for it in memory for example?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @SimonMourier just getting the IDCompositionDevice of the current WUX context, I don't want to cast the Compositor because I don't want/not allowed to use WinRT to do so

Comment: This doesn't explain what you are trying to do with this

Comment: @SimonMourier okay, so I'm (re)implementing Composition APIs for Win8 Jupiter apps (as a part of a toolkit I'm creating) so there's no W.U.C.Compositor there but it uses IDComposition* directly (I have checked with IDA). I didn't want to say so at the beginning so I don't get "Win8 Jupiter apps aren't supported", "you can't use Win32 APIs in Jupiter apps", "it won't be allowed in Store", "stop using that thing", "no, it's impossible in Jupiter" type of comments

Comment: So that's why I want this question to be dealt with as if it's in Win32
(Jupiter apps can read memory and call almost any function from any dll)

Comment: I don't think there's anything documented (and even stable). Note (most, not all, WUC typically is) WinRT APIs are accessible by Win32 code.